# Make dropdown menu always opened

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have menu which is open on click and close automatically. I'm not very much into *.js* and don't know how exactly work.

What I want is this menu to not close automatically. When is open to stay open.
This is the *.js*

```
 var current_item = 0;
 // few settings
 var section_hide_time = 400;
 var section_show_time = 400;

 // jQuery stuff
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 // Switch section
 $("a", '.mainmenu').click(function() 
 {
  if( ! $(this).hasClass('active') ) { 
     current_item = this;
     // close all visible divs with the class of .section
     $('.section:visible').fadeOut( section_hide_time, function() { 
        $('a', '.mainmenu').removeClass( 'active' );  
        $(current_item).addClass( 'active' );
        var new_section = $( $(current_item).attr('href') );
        new_section.fadeIn( section_show_time );
     } );
  }
  return false;
  });      
});
```

I suppose the part for open/close is in *switch* section but I'm not sure.

Comment: plz update the html code too for the drop down

Comment: Do you want it to close again when u click the original button or just to stay open till you load another page or close it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Toggle();`, then it won't close until you click the button again.

Answer (score 0):

The "section_show_time" is what is making the menu close automatically. If you take that out of the javascript it should stay open when opened. You might want to take out the "section_hide_time" as well if you don't want it to do anything with out a users click.

I would recommend using completely different javascript to make a open and close toggle button:

In the HTML file:

```
<button onclick="toggleMenu()"> </button> 
<div id="toggleMenu" style="display:none;">
    <"menu content here"> 
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  function toggleMenu() {
    if (document.getElementById("toggleMenu").style.display == "none"){
      document.getElementById("toggleMenu").style.display = "block";
    } else { 
      document.getElementById("toggleMenu").style.display = "none"; 
    }
  }
</script>
```

In js you could change out "block" to what ever you want the display to be when the menu is to be visible.